# How do I update js and css files without an updated version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, version

In this project, I don't have a license to make changes in my localhost. So, I made changes directly on the server / portal azure through the app service editor

My problem is every time changes the css and js file, I have to update the version

My index like this :

```
<html>
...
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style/combined.css?v=0.0.21">
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="/assets/script/combined.js?v=0.0.11" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/script/combined-inline.js?v=0.0.120" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, I make changes in combined.css. I have to upgrade the previous version v=0.0.21 to v=0.0.22 so that the website can be updated. I always do that when there is any change. And in my opinion this is not good

Is there another way that is simpler for my case?

Comment: disable any cache setting in your serve (which is a bad idea of course ..)

Comment: Use can use cache-control for browser caching.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If it's a bad idea, then what is a good idea? :)

Comment: is to keep doing what you are doing: updating the version each time you make a change

Comment: @TemaniAfif Are there no other ideas? Or can I make it more simple and dynamic? So it looks more cool

Comment: do a hard refresh of your browser each time you make a change https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/#.Xntr3YhKiUk

Comment: @TemaniAfif This website is accessed by many people. There's no way I would ask them to do a hard refresh

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to ask. if I upgrade the version every change. can i reset it? for example I use version v = 1.1. I made 8 changes, i.e. v = 1.2, v = 1.3, v = 1.4, v = 1.5, v = 1.6, v = 1.7, v = 1.8, v = 1.9. can i reset it? so for the next change I can go back to using v = 1.1

Comment: @palaѕн Maybe you can answer this question with a detail answer

Comment: you can go back to any version but it may still be cached by the browser, so you need to consider your server configuration and the cache period set. If it's set to 1 month then the file may be kept one month for any user

Comment: @Temani Afif Okay thanks